# Vagrant is not picking up laravel/homestead box

Tags: laravel, vagrant, homestead

I've downloaded the homestead box manually because of much slow downloading via terminal. But after adding the box, vagrant is not finding it and attempting to download again.

[image: Vagrant find error]

Comment: In what directory is it stored? Because slash is probably treated as special. My `ubuntu/trusty32` is stored in a directory `$VAGRANT_HOME/boxes/ubuntu-VAGRANTSLASH-trusty32`. Try that pattern or choose slash-less name.

Comment: I'm in windows so the path is C:\Users\Zayn\.vagrant.d\boxes\laravel-VAGRANTSLASH-homestead

Comment: And with this path it still doesn't find and wants to download?

Comment: Yes. i've shown the output above. It doesn't find it and start the download again

Comment: do you have a version indicated in your Vagrantfile ? it adds as v0 the box but it is looking for version >= 0.4.0 when vagrant up

Comment: can you also confirm you have vagrant 1.5 at least ?

Comment: Vagrant 1.8.1, and i tried to rename the folder v0 to 0.4.0 and it worked but in the process. it crashed and display this error The box 'laravel/homestead' is not a versioned box. The box was added
directly instead of from a box catalog. Vagrant can only
check the versions of boxes that were added from a catalog
such as from the public Vagrant Server.

Comment: does your folder contain a `metadata_url` file to point to the box url ? and within the vbox folder, do you have a `metadata.json` file

Comment: another possibility is to revert to folder v0 and specifically set `config.vm.box_check_update = false` in your Vagrantfile

Comment: Yes metadata.json but no metadata_url.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**@FrédéricHenri** Thanks. I found that the box was added directly instead of from a box catalog so vagrant try to check the updates and failed. So i simply just disable the check update.

`config.vm.box_check_update = false`

OR

For updates. I added `metadata_url` file in `laravel-VAGRANTSLASH-homestead` containing the url pointing to the box

`https://vagrantcloud.com/laravel/homestead`

Answer (score 0):

This happens when we add box from file, Vagrant marks as it is version `0` by default.

Solution I found When I got same error I renamed the folder `0` to the corresponding version in my case it was `0.4.2` inside this path`~/.vagrant.d/boxes/laravel-VAGRANTSLASH-homestead`. Then if you `vagrant up` from homestead project you may get error. So you can add catalog file `metadata_url` file. with url https://atlas.hashicorp.com/laravel/boxes/homestead in `laravel-VAGRANTSLASH-homestead` directory.